# How to copy files from sql server 2005 vm to sql server 2012 vm

Tags: sql-server-2005, virtual-machine

I want to copy a few files from E drive from my VM which has sql server 2005 and paste it to another VM which has sql server 2012.

I am not able to do it, as paste option is not available in my sql server 2012 vm.

What is wrong about this copy and paste.

Could anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: Your trying to copy on one virtual machine and paste on another? Think of each VM as a seperate computer your pressing copy on computer A walking across the room and pressing paste on computer B expecting it to work...

Comment: Then can you please suggest a way such that i can have these files in my other VM.I am connected to these VM on Remote desktop connection

Comment: Clarify which virtualization technology you are using: HyperV, VMWare, VirtualBox or else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both machines are on the same network, you can create a folder share on one VM and access that share from the other VM.  BTW, this has nothing to do with SQL.   [Sharing Folder on Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301281)